# Hyperledger composer REST API does not return transaction id

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Why is my composer REST server not returning the transaction id of the request, or where can I find the id?

```
 curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "$class": "org.example.biznet.SampleAsset", \ 
   "assetId": "1", \ 
   "value": "103300" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:3000/api/SampleAsset'
```

Response:

```
    {
  "date": "Sun, 04 Feb 2018 15:59:10 GMT",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "etag": "W/\"52-0IlZYwJKBE6+rHqbXGCNVeELkQ0\"",
  "x-download-options": "noopen",
  "x-frame-options": "DENY",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "http://localhost:3000",
  "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "vary": "Origin, Accept-Encoding",
  "content-length": "82",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
    }
```

As I can see in the pull request it should be solved: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/pull/843

My versions:

```
├── composer-cli@0.16.3
├── composer-playground@0.16.3
├── composer-rest-server@0.16.3
```

Comment: What you have posted looks like the headers, have you looked at the actual response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have submitted a POST request to an Asset (SampleAsset) which being an Asset does not generate a Transaction ID.  If you POST to a Transaction you will get a Transaction ID - and you will see it in the Response Body, not the Response Header.  See example below.

[image: Example Responses Body for a Transaction]

Comment: Ok, I see. But every change/write action to the fabric has an transaction id, am I right? You can see the transaction id off an asset change in the playground and in the Hyperledger Explorer.

Comment: Yes, and you can also see them on the REST server under /system/historian

Comment: Is there a reason why I cant get this id in the response? It is the same mechanism as in the Transaction POST.